# What kind of certificate do I need for http server with shared hosting?

Tags: smtp, hosting, certificate, shared

I need a certificate that affects each domain on my server. Those domains share the same ip but have different domain names (shared hosting) I'm wondering do I need a specific certificate for each of them or can I buy one certificate that applies to them all? 
The reason I need certificate is because the company which our server relays our clients mail to has blocked smtp port 25 so we need to use ssl port.

We are using Parallels Plesk btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can't in general host more than one SSL domain on a single ip address, unless you can get away with using a wildcard certificate (i.e. a certificate for *.example.com) or unless you can rely on all the people accessing your site having a browser with [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) enabled.

However I fail to see in what way the SSL certificate you use for you web hosting is an anyway relevant to using smtp over ssl. You don't need a certificate for that (unless your smtp host mandates the use of client side certificates, but that seems somewhat unlikely).